# how i rotate cube on button click in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

here is my code...cube is a perfect but i want rotate on button click.
eg..when i click front button then cube will be show front side same as other button
I did a lot of research but i did not find any solution
please anyone can help me..
[image]

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, cube;
    
    init();
    //drag();
    
    function init() {
    
        // renderer
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor ('#fff', 1);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
    
        // camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
     camera.position.x = 50;
     camera.position.y = 50;
     camera.position.z = 800;
    
        //cube
         var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(250, 350, 100,1,1,1);
      var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"red"});
    
        cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, cubeMaterial);
        //cube.doubleSided = true;
    
        cube.rotation.x = Math.PI / 1.5;
        cube.rotation.y = Math.PI / 1;
        // scene
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add(cube);
    
        // add subtle ambient lighting
        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x888888);
        scene.add(ambientLight);
    
        // directional lighting
        var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x666666);
        directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
        scene.add(directionalLight);
    
       
        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            //requestAnimFrame(render);
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
    
        render();
    }
```

```css
body {
margin: 0px;
}
#container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/r86/build/three.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You already have code which does some rotation:

```
cube.rotation.x = Math.PI / 1.5;
cube.rotation.y = Math.PI / 1;
```

Make yourself a set of functions which rotate the object to the desired angles and call them on buttons' clicks.